# Why does my shellcode testing program produce a segfault?

Tags: c, x86, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying to write a simple C program for testing if a given shellcode string works on my machine (64 bit), however every single attempt at running the below code results in a segmentation fault. Even though this "shellcode" is just some nop instructions and a break, can anybody explain what is going wrong? I've had similar experiences with shellcodes & shellcode testing programs written by other people, is there some recently introduced mitigation that I am not aware of? I am running: `5.9.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.1-1kali2 (2020-10-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CODE "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\xCC";

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)()) CODE;
    (int)(*func)();
}
```

This is the command/flags I use to compile the code.

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -no-pie -m64 -o shell shell.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0xCC at the end is `INT3` or a  which should result in `Trace/breakpoint trap`

If you change 0xCC to 0xC3, it will return without faulting.

One possible mitigation would be if your compiler is putting constant strings into .rdata instead of .text .

Instead of:

```
#define CODE #define CODE "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\xCC";
```

try

```
__attribute__((section(".text")))
static const unsigned char code[] = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\xCC";
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought by putting the string constant in the scope of main it would be placed on the stack, but I guess not.

Comment: @matt - you can guarantee stack placement with the seldom used `alloca()` function.

Comment: @Matt: It's a string literal that you only reference in main; that reference has type `char*` not `char[]`.  Think of a string literal like an anonymous `static char array[]` - it will always go in `.rodata`.  (Unless you use it as the initializer for a local `char array[] = "foo";` but then it's not exactly a string literal.  Then `-z execstack` will work even on modern Linux kernels where it really only makes the stack itself executable, not every readable page.  At least if you use `__builtin___clear_cache` which on x86 just tells GCC that this stored data isn't dead, but used as code.)